# Where can I find wifi profiles?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection, wifi-configuration, internet-security

Laptop recently got lost. Is there any way to grab the wifi profiles off of that laptop? Microsoft's sync doesn't work as both PC's have to be on a running for it to transmit data.

For example I connected to the school  wifi then proceeded to lose laptop. That wifi should be stored somewhere. How would I access it remotely.

Is there anywhere I can look where that data may be stored and accessed remotely?

Comment: Did you sync passwords to a Microsoft account?  If so they'll be [saved](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/devices/enterprise-state-roaming-windows-settings-reference#devices-and-endpoints) and you can sync to another PC.  You don't need both PC to be active but you **do** need to authenticate the PC you want to sync them to.  See if you can see both in [https://account.microsoft.com/devices/](https://account.microsoft.com/devices/)

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop is lost and gone, then you are not likely to be able to remote into it.

If you had a sturdy password, then the finder will not be able to start it. The windows admin password is disabled by default.

If, for whatever reason, the password is weak or non-existent, the wireless profiles are easy to find with the NETSH WLAN command.

Let's hope it was secured and so useless to the finder.

To your specific question, the data you want is only on the laptop - not anywhere else, unless you specifically saved the profiles to another device.